# Lost sudo privileges by renaming an essential folder

Tags: sudo

This was stupid of me, but now I can't fix it.  I changed the name of `/usr/lib` to `/usr/lib64` not realizing that the `sudoers.so` file was in this folder.

Now I can only log in in recovery and I have lost my `sudo` privileges (the computer cannot locate `/usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so`) and I cannot rename the file back from `lib64` to `lib` without `sudo` privileges.

Is there a work around to rename or copy this folder?

Answer (score 2):

Run a Live USB or DVD with Ubuntu. From there you can rename it..

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. I did not use a Live CD, but here's what I did:

1. Reboot the system and press <kbd>Shift</kbd> intermittently while Ubuntu started to load. That allows you to select the recovery mode, which takes you to a CLI with root privileges (thus you don't need sudo). Thats the second option in the list of boot options if I remember correctly.
2. Then run

   ```
   mount-o remount,rw /
   ```

   to remount your hard drive as read/write (read-only by default).
3. Rename your folder with

   ```
   mv /usr/lib64 /usr/lib
   ```

Your system should work fine after a regular reboot (issue the `reboot` command).

Answer (score 0):

If your in recovery mode enable networking to get rw access on your hard drive.
Drop into the root shell

mv /usr/lib65 /usr/lib

That should fix it.

Comment: *"enable networking to get rw access on your hard drive"* What? That does not make sense to me. And the remainder of this answer is [already provided as an answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/318664/88802).

Comment: enable networking option in safemode mounts the hard drive in rw mode.